# iOS - Pulldownmenu From Navigation Bar instead of View (top)

Tags: ios, objective-c, drop-down-menu, uinavigationbar

I am following and using this pulldownmenu from [here](https://github.com/BernardGatt/iOSPullDownMenu).

is it possible to launch the pulldownmenu from the bottom of the nav bar instead of all the way at the top (of the view)?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's probably better to ask this on the github page.  Create an issue and ask there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If posting the answer helps anyone, here it is:

```
pulldownMenu = [[PulldownMenu alloc] initWithView:self.view];
[self.view insertSubview:pulldownMenu atIndex:1];
```

:D